# Time difference between 2 dates results in wrong or unknown values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, timeago

I am trying to find the time difference between 2 dates. but i am getting values as `-0.0000`, `nan`, or `-357683564`. below is my code to find time difference. am i doing any wrong in this calculations ?

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
formatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:MM:SS ±HHMM";//MM/dd/yyyy
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setLocale:usLocale];
NSDate *intialTime= [formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateArray objectAtIndex:i]]];//[formatter dateFromString:@"12/11/2005"];
NSDate *presentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [presentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:intialTime];
int seconds = (int)ceil(timeInterval);
int mins = seconds / 60;
double secondsInAnHour = 3600;
NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = timeInterval / secondsInAnHour;
NSLog(@"Time interval in Mins:%d -- %.4f -- %d",mins,timeInterval,hoursBetweenDates);
```

**In Log :**

`Time interval in Mins:-35791394 -- nan -- -2147483648`

`intialTime - (null) and presentDate - 2014-05-09 10:30:15 +0000`

Comment: 1st mistake here : @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:MM:SS ±HHMM" it shoudl be `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"`

Comment: 2nd mistake: if your date is `12/11/2005` then your formatter is wrong.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - Thanks for reply. Even if i use `@"MM/dd/yyyy"` this format i get same output

Comment: 3rd: never do such a manual calculations like `/60` and `3600` as there are leap seconds and leap years. use **NSDateComponents** instead to find diff between two dates.

Comment: @Grey_Code : Wherever you are calculating NSTimeInterval, both the dates must be in same date format.

Comment: Log your NSDate objects and the individual NSTimeInterval values from them.

Comment: @Grey_Code - You are incorrect.  NSDate objects contain no date format (or timezone).

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - Calculating days difference using NSTimeIntervals will not be upset by leap days (though leap seconds could figure in, I suppose).

Comment: Hint: Learn how to debug.

Comment: OwnDate - 2014-05-09 02:27:52 ,PresentDate - 2014-05-09 13:23:41 +0000 , IntialTime - null

Comment: "OwnDate" doesn't appear anywhere above in your question, therefore it's meaningless noise.  And we have no idea what value `[dateArray objectAtIndex:i]` has -- not even clear whether it's an NSString or something else.  You've got a long way to go to learn how to characterize and debug a problem.

Comment: I have fixed my issue. thanks for helping friends. my problem was in timeZone as we retrieve date from web service. it was displaying date as their server date and my current date was not matching. also i have answers for my question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my Issue by using `NSTimeZone`. here was my problem.it was displaying date as their server date and my current date was not matching to timezone and not able to format it. Thanks for you all friends for helping me to find my mistake.

> ```
>     NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
>     [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

    NSDate *dateToday = [NSDate date];

    NSString *date = @"09-05-14";   // Put your initial date here...

    [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *todayString = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString *todaysDateTime = [date stringByAppendingString:todayString];

    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *initialDate = [df dateFromString:todaysDateTime];

    NSTimeInterval ti = [initialDate timeIntervalSinceDate:dateToday];
```

Comment: i am getting `0.000000`